# Bootstrap 4 Navbar not collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I just started using bootstrap 4, and I attempted to make a collapsing menu. When I click the button, the content shows perfectly fine. The problem is when I attempt to collapse the menu. When I click the button, it stutters but does not close.

Here is the code:

```
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-inverse">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bird">
             &#9776;
            </button>
            </nav>

            <!-- Content -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable" id="bird">
            <div class="bg-faded p-a">
            <h4>Test</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum is dummy text.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Nick

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/mqdytg69/ !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH go on eraoftech.net and tell me if that works

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is that you have 2 bootstrap js files included on your page ! CSS too !

Answer (score 0):

No problem in your code. Check required css and js files are included in code. And better o use bg-light and navbar-light.